# Multiple android studio on Mac

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-2.2, android-studio-2.3, android-studio-2.1

My system is `MacBook`, can I have one version from `android studio stable` and `android studio beta` on my system ?

I have `android studio 3.1.4 stable` on my system now.

Problem: I need to `android studio 3.2 beta` now.

I need to `stable` and `Beta`, I need to `beta` and to `stable` often.

Comment: have you even tried what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes... just download them and put the different versions in your applications folder. I'm currently running 3.1.4 stable, 3.2 beta 5, and 3.3 canary 5. The beta and canary versions will have a yellow icon.

Comment: @ tgrable. Thank's a lot.